# Virt-manager duplicating CAPSLOCK key press

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, virt-manager

I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME virtual machine using Virt-Manager. In all applications, I noticed that every time I tap the capslock key it triggers it, but then ~1s later it throws *another* capslock key.

This really throws me off when working in vim. For example, I would type something, exit insert mode by tapping capslock, quickly re-enter into insert mode, begin typing something else, and then suddenly realize that I was exited out of insert mode again in the middle of my typing (without me triggering it). The other capslock is thrown ~1s after hitting capslock.

The reason I think it's a virt-manager issue is because the same exact thing happens in my Debian 11 XFCE virtual machine.

**EDIT**: I realized this is a problem with the Caps Lock key, I just had it remapped to the ESC key. But even without remapping, the same problem happens.

found this bug, but no solution it seems
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/spice-gtk/-/issues/143

Comment: Do you have another keyboard handy just to make sure that the keyboard is not the problem?

Comment: yes, confirmed same problem happens with different keyboard

Comment: just realized that it's the capslock key that has this issue (see edits).

Comment: Possibly caused by the fact that Capslock toggles state, it is not a "normal" key (but that is just a guess).  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/427612 & https://gitlab.com/virt-viewer/virt-viewer/-/issues/29

Comment: Here is a workaround (not a fix) https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/spice/-/issues/66#note_1197486

Comment: @Gantendo I believe you are right, these are the relevant resources for the problem. But do I need to do the workaround for each keyboard? What if I re-pair my bluetooth keyboard, would I need to do it again? Does it work for Wayland or just Xorg sessions? Which package is causing this problem? Is the bug still there in the latest version of whatever that package is? Which file can I modify to fix this problem via modifying the source code/package code (if possible)?

Comment: also is there a way to create/set up the virtual machine using the virt-manager GUI to avoid running into this problem?

Comment: could there be a way to trick the VM into thinking that the capslock is actually ESC by changing it in the host and not remapping it in the guest VM? That way the guest would think that ESC is being pressed, never capslock?